# Store path in variable or a textfile. Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this code

```
FORFILES /p C:\tester\ /D -2 /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE chdir">testtest.txt
```

And it's already storing in the `testtest.txt`

This is my second code

```
FORFILES /p C:\tester\ /D -2 /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE @path ..\sc"
```

I want to store the path in the .txt or variable but I can't.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You have the exact proper syntax to do so in your first code snippet - what's stopping you from using it in the second? What does *I can't* mean **exactly**? What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: In second code I want to store the output of this line "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE @path ..\sc", I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can't store the output of that line to a text file, because it actually launches the app and opens the file for those files that have apps associated. For instance, if one of the files is `test.xls`, it will start Excel and open `test.xls` - what would you expect it to write to file for that?

Comment: If I can't store that in text file, can I store it on a variable or something that I can get or call? Because for example, the active directory is C:, but I'm working the files in D.

Comment: Again, *what are you expecting to store*? If the first file located is `test.txt`, the file will open in Notepad. Notepad opens, with `test.txt` loaded. **What would you expect to store to file or a variable or something?

Comment: I want to store the output of this line "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE @path ..\sc" which is indicating to the PATHS of FILES that have FALSE string.

Comment: No, that's **not** what the code is doing. It's trying to **run** each file. (Open a command prompt to a folder that has a few text files in it, and run `forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE @path ..\sc`, and see what happens.)

Comment: Yea yea I know that, so how can I store the '@path ..\sc' or the '@path' in a variable or txtfile.

Comment: So you're asking how to store the full name of each file to a text file (skipping directories)?

Comment: Yes, or atleast just the directory where the FALSE files came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you're just looking to list all files (not directories) and collect those filenames in a text file.

Just change the output to `@echo`, and redirect all output to the same file:

```
FORFILES /p C:\tester\ /D -2 /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE @echo @path " >> somefile.txt
```

You can add a path to the filename, of course, to put it in the directory of your choice.